# Send account info to client from cPanel

Tags: cpanel

I see a lot of hosting that when an account is created on their servers, an email is sent to the client with all info DB, FTP, Email, etc....

I was wondering if this tools is in cPanel or I need to install something else so new clients could receive the info automatically when the account is created in cPanel.

Could I create a custom email with those info?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clients should automatically get an email from cPanel when the account is created assuming you  passed their email address to the account setup wizard.

Comment: Yeah but how to customize that email ?